# How to create library that uses some other libraries?

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to create a graphic library (nothing serious, just to learn stuff). In Visual Studio I have one solution and two projects in it - dll and exe. For window management I use GLFW library. In my own window class I want to have a private memeber of GLFW Window structure. The problem is that my exe project doesn't know what GLFW is - it doesn't know where to find `#include <glfw/glfw3>`.

My question is - what's the proper way to create such library that uses other libraries? Setting the exe project to include all those libraries doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

Comment: A DLL project that uses other libraries is set up the exact same way as an EXE project that uses other libraries.

Comment: Are you talking about libraries or includes? They aren't the same. If you want to use `glfw3` (even coming in some sort from your `DLL`) you *have* to include the `glfw3` headers.

Comment: @Manuel I want to use GLFW library so in dll project I include ```<GLFW/glfw3.h>```. But the exe project doesn't know what GLFWWindow is, because it doesn't know where to find that header file. Do you mean that I should also include this file in my exe project?

Comment: @OftenDeadKanji yes. It has to know the *type*, and will get everything else (objects, functions, whatever) from the `DLL`.

Comment: @Manuel oh, ok. I decided to have seperate folder in my project directory for all files from other libraries. Then in project settings I added a proper relative path to it and also in my precompiled header file I include those headers with relative path. Now all library files (I use also GLAD that comes with .c file) know where to look for their headers and exe project knows everything now :) Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @OftenDeadKanji glad you found how to handle that. You could write a response to your own question and accept it so others can learn from your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Manuel I figured out how to do it: both - dll and exe projects, **have to** include libraries' header files.

My solution: in dll I use precompiled headers so all libraries' header files are included in that file with a **relative path**. In dll project settings I put proper paths so any libraries files will know how to find their headers. What's important is that my exe project includes one header file from my dll and that file include precompiled header so exe project 'knows' everything it needs about libraries.

Thanks again @Manuel for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using visual studio, then Microsofts documentation is a great place to get information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/dlls-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019 they have a description on DLL’s and how to create them and also how to link DLL’s to projects.